# ansible iterate over dictionary and a list

Tags: ansible

I have the following data:

```
vars:
    list_priv_keys: ['~/.ssh/id_rsa', '~/.ssh/id_ed25519']
    dict_pub_keys: {'~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub': false, '~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub': true}
```

I need to retrieve public keys from private ones only when pub_key doesn't exist (`dict_pub_keys.value == false`)

What do I have so far is this (which is obviously a wrong direction):

```
- name: "[CA_User] Retrieve public key form private if pub key file doesn't exist"
    command: "ssh-keygen -y -f {{ ????? }} > {{ item.key }}"
  with_dict: "{{ dict_pub_keys }}"
  when:
    - false in dict_pub_keys.values()
    - not item.value
```

How would you guys solve this task?

Comment: is the structure of those vars negotiable for modifications? also, you are using `{}` which indicate dictionary variable, but you probably refer to lists, which are enclosed in `[]`

Comment: 1 - yes, the structure is negotiable. 2 - good point, this is a typo, I will fix it.

Comment: and you can provide options like, creating different lists or dictionaries in order to achieve the goal. For example creating a list containing only public keys to be created.. etc..

Comment: ok, adding an answer

Answer (score -1):

since the var is open for modifications, i would suggest a list of dictionary elements that each one contains 3 attributes: the 2 file names and the true/false value that controls if we should take action or not:

```
  vars:
    dict_pub_keys: [{public_key: '~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub', priv_key: '~/.ssh/id_rsa', keyexists: false}, { public_key: '~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub', priv_key: '~/.ssh/id_ed25519', keyexists: true}]
```

and here is a task to loop over this list and run the ssh-keygen command if `keyexists == false` would be (i have commented the ssh-keygen command, and using a one that "walls" the command we would run):

```
  tasks:
    - name: "[CA_User] Retrieve public key form private if pub key file doesn't exist"
      # command: "ssh-keygen -y -f {{ item.priv_key }} > {{ item.public_key }}"
      command: "wall 'ssh-keygen -y -f {{ item.priv_key }} > {{ item.public_key }}'"
      when: item.keyexists == false
      loop: "{{ dict_pub_keys }}"
```

hope it helps

**UPDATE:**

about variable structure: you had 2 list variables containing partial information about the same object (the ssh key): 1st variable had the private key filename, the 2nd variable the public key filename and if it exists or not. we could combine them to a dictionary variable that contains:

```
{ public_key_filename: xxxx,
  private_key_filename: yyyy,
  file_exists: zzzz
}
```

dictionary variable is basically an object, you define key=value pairs to it.

by the way, the variable declaration could be also written in this alternative syntax (yml format), but plz pay attention to the indentations:

```
dict_pub_keys:
  - public_key: '~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub'
    priv_key: '~/.ssh/id_rsa'
    keyexists: false
  - public_key: '~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub'
    priv_key: '~/.ssh/id_ed25519'
    keyexists: true
```

Comment: That looks good, but please, include the process of creating this new var list-of-dictionaries from the initial vars.

Comment: sure, please check. [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-dictionaries-in-python-3) looks really good on dict variables.

Comment: I know how to set them initially, but those variables are not set, they are being created as a result of tasks. Therefore I need ansible task(s) in order to convert those variables from the existing ones to the structure you are suggesting.

Comment: Well, thats why i asked if the vars can be restructured in the first place. by the way, the 1st list variable (from your question) doesnt contain important information, we can work with only the 2nd variable you provided, the `dict_pub_keys`